# Aplication start slow after add onclick options

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with my prototype aplication.

1. When i add new data to realtime data base my calendar view and event list doesnt refresh. You think guys ich i send props from form.component to view.comopnent its a good solution?
2. When I add a function to my application that when the user clicks the mouse on a given day from the calendar and edits or deletes an event, it does not disappear from the view even though it is no longer in the database. I used fetch but it didn't help.
   I would like events to appear after pressing the date, and not all at once, but with this option, after editing or deleting, I have to refresh the page to have a new state.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useEventApi } from "./hooks/useEvent";

const CalendarView = () => {
  const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState(new Date().getFullYear());
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(new Date().getMonth());
  const [calendarDays, setCalendarDays] = useState([]);
  const daysOfWeek = ["Pon.", "Wt.", "Śr.", "Czw.", "Pią.", "Sob.", "Niedz."];

  const { getEvents, updateEvent, removeEvent } = useEventApi();
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const [editedText, setEditedText] = useState("");
  const [editingEventKey, setEditingEventKey] = useState(null);
  const [eventDates, setEventDates] = useState([]); 
  const [selectedDateEvents, setSelectedDateEvents] = useState([]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const eventDatesFromDatabase = events.map((event) => new Date(event.date));
    setEventDates(eventDatesFromDatabase); 
  }, [events]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 0).getDay();
    const lastDateOfMonth = new Date(
      currentYear,
      currentMonth + 1,
      0
    ).getDate();
    const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0).getDay();

    const days = Array.from({ length: firstDayOfMonth }, () => 0)
      .concat(Array.from({ length: lastDateOfMonth }, (_, i) => i + 1))
      .concat(Array.from({ length: (7 - lastDayOfMonth + 7) % 7 }, () => 0));

    setCalendarDays(days);
  }, [currentYear, currentMonth]);

  const handlePrevMonth = () => {
    setCurrentMonth((prevMonth) => {
      if (prevMonth === 0) {
        setCurrentYear((prevYear) => prevYear - 1);
        return 11;
      }
      return prevMonth - 1;
    });
  };

  const handleNextMonth = () => {
    setCurrentMonth((prevMonth) => {
      if (prevMonth === 11) {
        setCurrentYear((prevYear) => prevYear + 1);
        return 0;
      }
      return prevMonth + 1;
    });
  };

  const getCurrentDay = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    if (
      today.getFullYear() === currentYear &&
      today.getMonth() === currentMonth
    ) {
      return today.getDate();
    }
    return -1;
  };

  const fetchEvents = async () => {
    const eventList = await getEvents();
    setEvents(eventList);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchEvents();
  }, []);

  const handleEditEvent = (event) => {
    setEditedText(event.text);
    setEditingEventKey(event.key);
    console.log("Edit event with key:", event.key);
  };

  const handleSaveEvent = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (editedText !== "" && editingEventKey !== null) {
      await updateEvent(editingEventKey, editedText);
      fetchEvents();
      setEditedText("");
      setEditingEventKey(null);
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteEvent = async (event) => {
    try {
      await removeEvent(event.key);
      fetchEvents();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error removing events:", error);
    }
  };
  const isSameDay = (date1, date2) => {
    return (
      date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear() &&
      date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
      date1.getDate() === date2.getDate()
    );
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchEvents();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="Kalendarz">
      <div className="calendar-view">
        <div className="calendar-header">
          <button onClick={handlePrevMonth}>&#8249;</button>
          <h2>
            {new Date(currentYear, currentMonth).toLocaleString("default", {
              month: "long",
              year: "numeric",
            })}
          </h2>
          <button onClick={handleNextMonth}>&#8250;</button>
        </div>
        <ul className="calendar-week-day">
          {daysOfWeek.map((day) => (
            <li key={day} className="day-label">
              {day}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <div className="calendar-days">
          {calendarDays.map((day, index) => {
            const currentDate = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, day);
            const isEventDate = eventDates.some((eventDate) =>
              isSameDay(eventDate, currentDate)
            );

            if (day === 0) {
              return <div key={index} className="calendar-day empty"></div>;
            } else {
              return (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className={`calendar-day ${
                    day === getCurrentDay() ? "current-date" : ""
                  } ${isEventDate ? "event-details" : ""}`}
                >
                  {day}
                </div>
              );
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="calendar-events-container">
        <div className="calendar-form">
          <form onSubmit={handleSaveEvent}>
            <input
              className="form-group-input"
              placeholder="Edit"
              type="text"
              value={editedText}
              onChange={(e) => setEditedText(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
            <button className="simple-btn" type="submit">
              Zapisz
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div className="calendar-list-container">
          <h3>Events:</h3>
          {events.map((event) => (
            <div key={event.key} className="calendar-list-item">
              <span className="event-list-title">{event.text}</span>
              <button
                className="edit-btn"
                onClick={() => handleEditEvent(event)}
              >
                <span className="material-symbols-outlined">edit</span>
              </button>
              <button
                className="delete-btn"
                onClick={() => handleDeleteEvent(event)}
              >
                <span className="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CalendarView;
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useEventApi } from "./hooks/useEvent";

const CalendarView = () => {
  const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState(new Date().getFullYear());
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(new Date().getMonth());
  const [calendarDays, setCalendarDays] = useState([]);
  const daysOfWeek = ["Pon.", "Wt.", "Śr.", "Czw.", "Pią.", "Sob.", "Niedz."];

  const { getEvents, updateEvent, removeEvent } = useEventApi();
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const [editedText, setEditedText] = useState("");
  const [editingEventKey, setEditingEventKey] = useState(null);
  const [eventDates, setEventDates] = useState([]); 
  const [selectedDateEvents, setSelectedDateEvents] = useState([]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const eventDatesFromDatabase = events.map((event) => new Date(event.date));
    setEventDates(eventDatesFromDatabase); 
  }, [events]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 0).getDay();
    const lastDateOfMonth = new Date(
      currentYear,
      currentMonth + 1,
      0
    ).getDate();
    const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0).getDay();

    const days = Array.from({ length: firstDayOfMonth }, () => 0)
      .concat(Array.from({ length: lastDateOfMonth }, (_, i) => i + 1))
      .concat(Array.from({ length: (7 - lastDayOfMonth + 7) % 7 }, () => 0));

    setCalendarDays(days);
  }, [currentYear, currentMonth]);

  const handlePrevMonth = () => {
    setCurrentMonth((prevMonth) => {
      if (prevMonth === 0) {
        setCurrentYear((prevYear) => prevYear - 1);
        return 11;
      }
      return prevMonth - 1;
    });
  };

  const handleNextMonth = () => {
    setCurrentMonth((prevMonth) => {
      if (prevMonth === 11) {
        setCurrentYear((prevYear) => prevYear + 1);
        return 0;
      }
      return prevMonth + 1;
    });
  };

  const getCurrentDay = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    if (
      today.getFullYear() === currentYear &&
      today.getMonth() === currentMonth
    ) {
      return today.getDate();
    }
    return -1;
  };

  const fetchEvents = async () => {
    const eventList = await getEvents();
    setEvents(eventList);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchEvents();
  }, []);

  const handleEditEvent = (event) => {
    setEditedText(event.text);
    setEditingEventKey(event.key);
    console.log("Edit event with key:", event.key);
  };

  const handleSaveEvent = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (editedText !== "" && editingEventKey !== null) {
      await updateEvent(editingEventKey, editedText);
      fetchEvents();
      setEditedText("");
      setEditingEventKey(null);
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteEvent = async (event) => {
    try {
      await removeEvent(event.key);
      fetchEvents();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error removing events:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleCalendarDayClick = (day) => {
    const selectedDate = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, day);

    const eventsForSelectedDate = events.filter((event) =>
      isSameDay(new Date(event.date), selectedDate)
    );

    setSelectedDateEvents(eventsForSelectedDate);
  };

  const isSameDay = (date1, date2) => {
    return (
      date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear() &&
      date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
      date1.getDate() === date2.getDate()
    );
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchEvents();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="Calendar">
      <div className="calendar-view">
        <div className="calendar-header">
          <button onClick={handlePrevMonth}>&#8249;</button>
          <h2>
            {new Date(currentYear, currentMonth).toLocaleString("default", {
              month: "long",
              year: "numeric",
            })}
          </h2>
          <button onClick={handleNextMonth}>&#8250;</button>
        </div>
        <ul className="calendar-week-day">
          {daysOfWeek.map((day) => (
            <li key={day} className="day-label">
              {day}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <div className="calendar-days">
          {calendarDays.map((day, index) => {
            const currentDate = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, day);
            const isEventDate = eventDates.some((eventDate) =>
              isSameDay(eventDate, currentDate)
            );
  
            if (day === 0) {
              return <div key={index} className="calendar-day empty"></div>;
            } else {
              return (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => handleCalendarDayClick(day)} 
                  className={`calendar-day ${
                    day === getCurrentDay() ? "current-date" : ""
                  } ${isEventDate ? "event-details" : ""}`}
                >
                  {day}
                </div>
              );
            }
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="calendar-events-container">
        <div className="calendar-form">
          <form onSubmit={handleSaveEvent}>
            <input
              className="form-group-input"
              placeholder="Edit"
              type="text"
              value={editedText}
              onChange={(e) => setEditedText(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
            <button className="simple-btn" type="submit">
              Save
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div className="calendar-list-container">
        <h3>Events:</h3>
        {selectedDateEvents.map((event) => (
          <div key={event.key} className="calendar-list-item">
            <span className="event-list-title">{event.text}</span>
            <button
              className="edit-btn"
              onClick={() => handleEditEvent(event)}
            >
              <span className="material-symbols-outlined">edit</span>
            </button>
            <button
              className="delete-btn"
              onClick={() => handleDeleteEvent(event)}
            >
              <span className="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
};

export default CalendarView;
```

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */
import { push, ref, update, remove, get} from 'firebase/database';
import { db, auth } from '../../../firebase';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

export const useEventApi = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const path = `calendar/${user?.uid}`;

  const getEvents = async () => {
    const eventsSnapshot = await get(ref(db, path));
    const eventsObject = eventsSnapshot.val();

    if (eventsObject) {
      return Object.keys(eventsObject).map((key) => ({
        key,
        ...eventsObject[key],
      }));
    }

    return [];
  };

  const addEvent = (text, selectedDate, selectedMonth, selectedYear) => {
    const eventData = {
      text: text,
      date: `${selectedYear}-${selectedMonth}-${selectedDate}`,
    };
    push(ref(db, path), eventData);
  };

  const removeEvent = (id) => {
    remove(ref(db, `${path}/${id}`));
  };

  const getEventByKey = async (id) => {
    if (!id) {
      return null;
    }

    const snapshot = await get(ref(db, `${path}/${id}`));
    return snapshot.val() || null;
  };

  const updateEvent = async (eventId, newTextValue) => {
    const eventPath = `${path}/${eventId}`;
    const updates = { text: newTextValue };
    
    try {
      await update(ref(db, eventPath), updates);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating event:", error);
    }
  };

  return {
    updateEvent,
    getEventByKey,
    removeEvent,
    addEvent,
    getEvents,
  };
};
```